# Javascript pulling from excel

Tags: javascript, excel

I am making Javascript/html program(all local, no server side code) that pulls info from certain rows of an excel file.  That part all works fine up until i want to switch to a new tab in the same file.  Is there a command to have the javascript switch excel tabs?  Also is there a way to make it so after i read in a line then close the excel process (it creates a new process each time i pull data) automatically?

Here is a snippet of the important part:

```
    var Excel;
    Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    Excel.Visible = false;
    Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/test.xlsx").ActiveSheet.Cells(row+1,x).Value;
    Excel.Quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since An ActiveXObject object has no intrinsic properties or methods, and uses the methods inherent to the object itself, you might try:

```
Excel.Sheets("Sheet2").Select;
```

You might have to use the workbooks method prior to using the sheets method also, like this:

```
Excel.Workbooks("MyWorkbook").Sheets("Sheet2").Select;
```

For javascript execution, not sure if you have to add `()` after the `Select` call.

Comment: If it was the answer above, go ahead an check it correct. Thanks!