# letting users import an excel document and then populating a page with it

Tags: javascript, html, excel

for my website, I need to create a button where a user is prompted to import an excel file, and then be able to use that data in an html file, for example, to put in a div tag.

I've searched stack overflow, but the closest I could find was [Javascript pulling from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768503/javascript-pulling-from-excel)

Which only works for internet explorer and doesn't explain how to import or export the excel file.

Can this sort of thing even be done?

Comment: I don't believe you can access the actual file data in an input with javascript. You might be best posting it to the server, processing it there, then returning some result

Comment: Would the processing be done in another language? for example, php or java?

Comment: @Captian-Dando Yes Sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will likely have to process the `excel` file on the server. Or have the user present a CSV file (exported from excel) that can be processed using javascript.

The site could upload the excel format data, then process on the server using -:

- PHP - http://phpexcel.codeplex.com

OR

- on the server export the excel file to CSV and use a javascript
  library to process (such as this `Node.js` library
  https://github.com/koles/ya-csv).

Client-side there is a javascript library http://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/ which would facilitate output of CSV data using js. But that 
requires CSV format.

Comment: could I send the imported file to the server via ajax?